# Casbah Scala MongoDB driver - a strange error

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I am trying to use Casbah, I get a strange error right in the beginning, on this line:

```
val mongoDB = MongoConnection("MyDatabase")
```

the error on MongoConenction says:

> class file needed by MongoConnection is missing. reference type
>   MongoOptions of package com.mongodb refers to nonexisting symbol.

I do not know what to do with this. The jars that I have attached to my projects are:

```
casbah-commons_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
casbah-core_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
casbah-gridfs_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
casbah-query_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
casbah-util_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

which looks like a full setup of Casbah and I do not understand what it might be yearning for. So there is the question number one - what do I have to do to resolve this problem?

The question number two is - the Casbah [tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.5.0/tutorial.html#import-the-driver) says that I could import just one thing, and get the `mongoConn()` method, which is also not truth. The `mongoConn()` simply does not get found if I follow the instructions. So, how can I acheive that everythong works as in the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the details of your setup, but it seems like you are not referencing the dependencies of the casbah-commons module.

According to the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.5.0/setting_up.html#id1), those are:

> mongo-java-driver, scalaj-collection, scalaj-time, JodaTime, slf4j-api